# show/hide password text using Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, show-hide, angular2-nativescript

I want to show/hidden password text in my login form. I have a code like below.

I try this code:

```
    <GridLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <StackLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center" [formGroup]="signUpForm" padding="15">
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField formControlName="username" hint="Username"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField formControlName="password" hint="Password" secure="true">
                </TextField>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label text ="show/hide" (tap)="toggleShow()"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
   </GridLayout>
```

In component.ts I write this code:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    signUpForm: FormGroup;
    show = false;
    type=  'password';
    constructor(....) {
        this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ["", Validators.required],
            password: ["", Validators.required]
        });
    }
    toggleShow()
    {
        this.show = !this.show;
        if (this.show){
            this.type = "text";
        }
        else {
            this.type = "password";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the function `toggleShow()` in     `console.log(this.show)`  show true false, but in template doesn't show nothing. Can you ask me any idea please, what is wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: SeanStanden posted a better solution, which should be the accepted answer.

Personally, I'd prefer to alter the `secure` property on the Textfield using element references:

.ts:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    @ViewChild('passwordField') passwordField: ElementRef;

    constructor() { }

    toggleShow() {
        console.log(this.passwordField.nativeElement.secure);
        this.passwordField.nativeElement.secure = !this.passwordField.nativeElement.secure;
    }
}
```

.html:

```
<GridLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
    <StackLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center" padding="15">
        <StackLayout class="input-field">
            <TextField hint="Username"></TextField>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="input-field">
            <TextField #passwordField hint="Password" secure="true">
            </TextField>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label text="show/hide" (tap)="toggleShow()"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

example playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Xmy1Pv&v=3

Comment: Ahh yeah, I just saw your solution below. I agree, that's a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason to access the native element. You can bind to the 'secure' property and toggle e.g.:

```
<StackLayout class="input-field">
   <TextField formControlName="password" hint="Password" [secure]="securePassword">
   </TextField>
</StackLayout>
<Label text ="show/hide" (tap)="toggleShow()"></Label>
```

TS

```
toggleShow() {
  this.securePassword = !this.securePassword;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An extension to Sean's answer specifically for **NativeScript-Vue** if anyone is looking for it.

```
<TextField class="input" :text="password" :secure="securePassword" ></TextField>

<Label class="passmsg" :text="passmsg" @tap="toggleShow()"></Label>
```

In Methods:

```
toggleShow () {
  this.securePassword = !this.securePassword
  if (this.securePassword) this.passmsg = 'Show Password'
  else this.passmsg = 'Hide Password'
}
```

Add `passmsg` in your data section

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below.

```
<StackLayout class="input-field">
    <TextField formControlName="password" [hint]="passwordType" secure="true"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

TS:-

```
passwordType: string = "password";
toggleShow()
    {
        this.passwordType = (this.passwordType == "password") ? "text" : "password";
    }
```

Hope this helps.